# Automatically add interest every month

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I have a MySQL database which should cover the amount transaction of account/client. This database contains two tables, one is `clientInfo` the other is `transaction`.

- `clientInfo` contains the all information about account/client.
- `transaction` table contains all the information relating transactions done with the accounts.

**Problem:**

Every month I have to add interest to each account according to as their available information in `clientInfo` and have to add this to `transaction` table too. I can do it manually using following PHP code.

```
$query = "SELECT id,balance,percentage from clientInfo";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_Array($result)){
$ID = $row['ID'];
$balance = $row['balance'];
$percentage = $row['percent'];

$debit = $balance * $percentage / 100;
$balance += debit;
$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO transaction VALUES ( $ID,$debit,$balance);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set cron job and it will run the query on specified time.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to utilize [MySql events](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html) for that

```sql
CREATE EVENT event_add_interest
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH STARTS LAST_DAY(CURDATE())
DO
  INSERT INTO transaction
  SELECT id, balance * percent / 100, balance + (balance * percent / 100)
    FROM clientInfo;
```

Use `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to check if event scheduler is enabled. If it's ON you should see a process "`Daemon`" by user "`event_scheduler`".
Use `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`to enable the scheduler if it's currently not enabled.
More on configuring event scheduler [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html)

Comment: can i insert multiple transaction records of adding interest into table using this event handler? like 
`CREATE EVENT event_add_interest
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH STARTS LAST_DAY(CURDATE())
DO
   INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (...);`

but this should add every update made for interest in transaction table

Comment: @RameshKarn You can think of an event as a special type of stored procedure that is scheduled to execute at certain time and(or) intervals. Therefore you can have as many statements in it as you want . If there are more then one then you just need to wrap them in a `BEGIN ... END block`. Now I did not understand from your comment what exactly you want to do with your data. SO if you want me to help you edit your question and add sample data and desired result based on that data.

Comment: @peterm.. sorry for late reply, i have updated my question. can i use those php script in the DO list of event ??

Comment: @peterm sorry for comment in here cause it's been quite long time, please go here http://prntscr.com/a3e7jq i set event in early month but nothing change then i create simple event to test all event working good , you can look at here http://prntscr.com/a3e7n5 it give me success delete data with 10 second, how can i debug for month ? i just change date local and nothing happen

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the way you're doing this isn't very efficient - you're retrieving all your accounts, and then one by one inserting the interest transaction. As the number of accounts grows, the PHP script will slow down; eventually, it will exceed the script time out setting for PHP, and then some of your accounts will have the interest applied, and some won't.

Instead, you can do it all in SQL:

```
insert  into transaction
select  ID, 
        balance * percentage / 100, 
        balance
from    clientinfo
```

this should be significantly faster, and you can wrap it in a transaction to guarantee it either all works or all fails.

The two options you have for running this automatically are MySQL events (as peterM suggests) or your operating system's task scheduler (Cron, on *nix systems). I don't much like "magical events" in databases, though - they often run at just the time you don't need them, they are hard to debug, and it's easy to forget about them and schedule conflicting events (e.g. an operating system upgrade). I definitely would recommend limiting their use.

Finally, your solution appears incomplete - because you're storing the balance in two places (client info and transactions), you have to update it in both places; the code you provide only updates it in transaction. That's probably a bug...

EDIT: one of the major lessons from database normalization is not to store information in more than one place. Logically, the balance of any one account should be the sum of all the transactions that have occurred for that account. So, in a properly normalized database design, you'd not have a "balance" column at all - you'd do something like:

```
select ai.account_id, 
       sum(t.debit)
from   acountInfo ai, 
       transaction t
where  ai.id = t.account_id
group by ai.account_id
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, that's really a bug, it need to update the clientInfo table too. can we update two table in single event?
i have one question about your query, what if i have some more values to insert into the transaction table, how can i merge those column with SELECT statement.

Comment: i will give it a try.
i got little confused with your comment on running it automatically: i guess you suggested to use OS task Scheduler. ( i am working on window 7, do you have any recommendation for win7 ?)

Comment: Task Scheduler is the way to go - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler